How to Access Customer Location User Defined Field Defined in CR.Standalone.Location from Sales Order Graph ACUMATICA
I have a user defined field in customer screen (LocationExt.usrExpectedPaymentDate) as below,
User Defined Field in Customer Screen
I need to access this field for a calculation in the sales order entry graph but I get this error.
[2024-10-23 04:45:10.957] \App_Code\Caches\SOOrderEntry.cs(159): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StandaloneLocationExt' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using PX.Common;
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.AP;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using PX.Objects.CA;
using PX.Objects.CM;
using PX.Objects.CR;
using PX.Objects.CS;
using PX.Objects.DR;
using PX.Objects.EP;
using PX.Objects.GL;
using PX.Objects.IN;
using PX.Objects.PM;
using PX.Objects.PO;
using PX.Objects.TX;
using POLine = PX.Objects.PO.POLine;
using POOrder = PX.Objects.PO.POOrder;
using PX.CarrierService;
using PX.Concurrency;
using CRLocation = PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.Location;
using PX.Objects.AR.CCPaymentProcessing;
using PX.Objects.AR.CCPaymentProcessing.Common;
using PX.Objects.AR.CCPaymentProcessing.Helpers;
using PX.Objects.AR.CCPaymentProcessing.Interfaces;
using ARRegisterAlias = PX.Objects.AR.Standalone.ARRegisterAlias;
using PX.Objects.AR.MigrationMode;
using PX.Objects.Common;
using PX.Objects.Common.Discount;
using PX.Objects.Common.Extensions;
using PX.Objects.IN.Overrides.INDocumentRelease;
using PX.CS.Contracts.Interfaces;
using Message = PX.CarrierService.Message;
using PX.TaxProvider;
using PX.Data.DependencyInjection;
using PX.Data.WorkflowAPI;
using PX.LicensePolicy;
using PX.Objects.Extensions.PaymentTransaction;
using PX.Objects.SO.GraphExtensions.CarrierRates;
using PX.Objects.SO.GraphExtensions.SOOrderEntryExt;
using PX.Objects.SO.Attributes;
using PX.Objects.Common.Attributes;
using PX.Objects.Common.Bql;
using OrderActions = PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntryActionsAttribute;
using PX.Objects.SO.DAC.Projections;
using PX.Data.BQL.Fluent;
using PX.Data.Localization;
using PX.Data.Reports;
using PX.Objects.IN.DAC.Accumulators;
using PX.Data.BQL;
using PX.Objects.SO.Standalone;
using PX.Objects;
using PX.Objects.SO;
using CFMWT22072024;

namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
  public class SOOrderEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry>
  {
    #region Event Handlers
protected void SOLine_UsrAnticipatedInvDate_FieldUpdated(PXCache sender, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
     var row = e.Row as SOLine;
            if (row == null) return;

            // Fetch the Sales Order
            SOOrder order = PXSelect<SOOrder,
                Where<SOOrder.orderNbr, Equal<Required<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>
                .Select(Base, row.OrderNbr);
            if (order == null) return;

            // Fetch the Terms
            Terms terms = PXSelect<Terms,
                Where<Terms.termsID, Equal<Required<Terms.termsID>>>>
                .Select(Base, order.TermsID)
                .RowCast<Terms>()
                .FirstOrDefault();
            if (terms == null) return;

            // Get the anticipated invoice date from SOLine
            SOLineExt soLineExt = sender.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(row);
            DateTime? anticipatedInvoiceDate = soLineExt.UsrAnticipatedInvDate;
            if (anticipatedInvoiceDate == null) return;

            // Get the payment terms days
            int termsDays = terms.DayDue00.GetValueOrDefault();

            // Fetch the Location
            //Location location = PXSelect<Location,
            //    Where<Location.bAccountID, Equal<Required<Location.bAccountID>>,
             //   And<Location.locationID, Equal<Required<Location.locationID>>>>>
            //    .Select(Base, order.CustomerID, order.CustomerLocationID)
             //   .RowCast<Location>()
             //   .FirstOrDefault();
            //if (location == null) return;

            // Get the Location extension to access custom fields
           // LocationExt locationExt = PXCache<Location>.GetExtension<LocationExt>(location);
            // Fetch the Location using the CRLocation alias
    CRLocation location = PXSelect<CRLocation,
        Where<CRLocation.bAccountID, Equal<Required<CRLocation.bAccountID>>,
        And<CRLocation.locationID, Equal<Required<CRLocation.locationID>>>>>
        .Select(Base, order.CustomerID, order.CustomerLocationID)
        .RowCast<CRLocation>()
        .FirstOrDefault();
    if (location == null) return;

    // Get the Location extension to access custom fields
    StandaloneLocationExt locationExt = PXCache<CRLocation>.GetExtension<StandaloneLocationExt>(location);

            if (locationExt?.UsrExpectedPaymentDate == null) return;

            // Get the additional days from the Location UDF
            int additionalDays = locationExt.UsrExpectedPaymentDate.Value.Day;

            // Calculate the final expected payment date:
            // Anticipated Invoice Date + Terms Days + Additional Days from Location
            DateTime expectedPaymentDate = anticipatedInvoiceDate.Value
                .AddDays(termsDays)
                .AddDays(additionalDays);

            // Update the expected payment date in the SOLine
            sender.SetValueExt<SOLineExt.usrExpectedPaymentDate>(row, expectedPaymentDate);
}
}
}

How can I access this field in order to process my calculation?
Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

The compiler can't find the  StandaloneLocationExt type that is used on this line for example. StandaloneLocationExt locationExt = PXCache.GetExtension(location);

How can I access the extension in Acumatica for the user defined field?

We don't know your project, your integrations and your configurations. We can help you with well defined problems in an isolated context that can be replicated. So we don't know how to help you unless u can create/present a problem that can be replicated by us to investigate it.

For the namespace problem, it appears you are missing a "using for PX.Objects.GDPR ?

For the namespace problem, it appears you are missing a "using for PX.Objects.GDPR ? I am not sure whether or not your UDF field is a field added to Location table in SQL (eg. it looks like a PXCacheExtension of PX.Objects.CR.Location, not StandaloneLocationExt, but check your DAC code and where you created UsrExpectedPaymentDate and change code to something like:
location.GetExtension<LocationExt>();) 

or a BAccountKvExt value stored as UDF
(eg.
select * from baccountkvext where FieldName like '%ExpectedPaymentDate%')

If the latter, those KvExt fieldName have a leading string "Attribute".
Below is an example that reads the ContactKvExt table to locate the Contact record of the given Customer:
if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            // find the corresponding ContactID in the System
            Contact contact = PXSelectJoin<Contact,
                InnerJoin<ContactKvExt, On<Contact.noteID, Equal<ContactKvExt.recordID>>>,
                Where<Contact.bAccountID, Equal<Required<Contact.bAccountID>>,
                   And<ContactKvExt.fieldName, Equal<Required<ContactKvExt.fieldName>>,
                And<ContactKvExt.valueString, Equal<Required<ContactKvExt.valueString>>>>>>
                .Select(Base, row.CustomerID, "AttributeORDBY", (string)e.NewValue);


I was able to access the custom field using this line of code since I needed to access the custom field from Shipping tab of Customers screen from SOOrderEntry graph.
var locationExt = cache.GetExtension<PX.Objects.CR.Standalone.LocationExt>(row);

